# Terms for different dependent items contributing to a whole?

Tags: terminology

I have a calculation that involves a number of items. It produces a single value. However, I would like to also show how much each item contributed to the final score.

The calculation is rather complex and different items can have synergies that boost the final score.

My current approach is to perform the calculation without each item and use the differences in final score to visualize how much each contributes. So to find out what item A is contributing, I calculate with all items and then all items except A and subtract these values.

Is there a term for calculating these dependent contributions to a complex whole... Or a better approach that I just missed in my research?